# Giving attribute error when i override create function in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-8

In my module i have overridden the create method as follows,

```
def create(self,vals):
    self.setState()
    return super(class_name,self).create(vals)

def setState(self):
    self.temp = False
```

It is giving attribute error as env not found in the model. How to rectify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `temp` a regular boolean field on the model? - Then you could just do this:

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    vals['temp'] = False
    return super(class_name,self).create(vals)
```

Comment: This is giving error as  create() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)

Comment: Sounds like a confusion between version 7 and version 8 code. Try to decorate your method with `@api.model` (I have updated the answer).

Answer (score 1):

In this way we can override create and write method in new API

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    //Your code goes here//
    return super(class_name, self).create(vals)

@api.multi
def write(self,vals,context=None):
    //Your code goes here//
    return super(class_name,self).write(vals)
```